# Import sql database into RAILs app

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, import

I have application written in php that communicates with  mysql database. I have created database with phpmyadmin but now i decided to create api application with rails so i would like to import my database in my new application. I have sql file but dont know how to import it to create all necessary tables?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Since Rails has conventions that PHP doesn't (strictly follow anyway) it's easier to re-engineer your database from Rails' point of view, you can later import data from your existing database into your rails database through migrations altho I have no experience in actually doing that kind of thing up until now :).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Sequel to map you database in ruby. I have write a blog post: http://cristianogregnanin.com/2015/07/22/Use-Capybara-and-Rspec-to-test-non-Rails-applications.html

Comment: Since his/her question is tagged with [tag:ruby-on-rails] his/her adapter will be arel so this answer does not really apply to the situation except for adding more gems than required to the application

Comment: Sequel works very well in this situation, I have use it in many similar context, is surelly better thaa Active Record for this task.